# Matlab update plot with multiple data lines/curves

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to update a plot with multiple data lines/curves as fast as possible. I have seen some method for updating the plot like using:

```
h = plot(x,y);
set(h,'YDataSource','y')
set(h,'XDataSource','x')
refreshdata(h,'caller');
```

or

```
set(h,'XData',x,'YData',y);
```

For a single curve it works great, however I want to update not only one but multiple data curves. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting `x` to be a `Nx2` matrix?

Comment: You can use the `drawnow` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ander Biguri. I tried the following code but it seems like it only allows a vector, not a 2D array.
`x(:,1) = (1:10); x(:,2) = (1:10);
y(:,1) = 2*x(:,1); y(:,2) = 5*x(:,2);
h = plot(x,y);
% give x,y new data.
set(d1,'XData',x,'YData',y);

Error using ==> set. Value must be a column or row vector .`

Comment: Thank @obchardon. I used `drawnow`, but it's still kind of slow. I want to have a faster updating :d

Comment: @bienle strange, on my computer i update a 1x1000 vector 100 time per second and there is no lag :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create multiple plot objects with a single `plot` command, the handle returned by `plot` is actually [an array of plot objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#outputarg_h) (one for each plot).

```
plots = plot(rand(2));
size(plots)

    1   2
```

Because of this, you *cannot* simply assign another [2x2] matrix to the `XData`.

```
set(plots, 'XData', rand(2))
```

You *could* pass a cell array of new XData to the plots via the following syntax. This is only really convenient if you already have your new values in a cell array.

```
set(plots, {'XData'}, {rand(1,2); rand(1,2)})
```

The other options is to update each plot object individually with the new values.  As far as doing this quickly, there really isn't much of a performance hit by not setting them all at once, because they will not actually be rendered until MATLAB is idle or you explicitly call `drawnow`.

```
X = rand(2);
Y = rand(2);

for k = 1:numel(plots)
    set(plots(k), 'XData', X(k,:), 'YData', Y(k,:))
end

% Force the rendering *after* you update all data
drawnow
```

If you really want to use the `XDataSource` and `YDataSource` method that you have shown, you can actually do this, but you would need to specify a unique data source for *each* plot object.

```
% Do this when you create the plots
for k = 1:numel(plots)
    set(plots(k), 'XDataSource', sprintf('X(%d,:)', k), ...
                  'YDataSource', sprintf('Y(%d,:)', k))
end

% Now update the plot data
X = rand(2);
Y = rand(2);

refreshdata(plots)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drawnow`:

```
%Creation of the vectors

x = 1:100;
y = rand(1,100);

%1st plot 
h = plot(x,y);

pause(2);

%update y
y = rand(1,100);
set(h,'YData',y)
%update the plot.
drawnow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question today. I was using the strategy you described to plot a single line, but it didn't work when plotting multiple lines to the same plot. I was inspired by Suever's solution, which is similar to what I did.

I was trying to do this for a 3x3 subplot, but I think the idea should generalize.

First I created an axes object using the tight_subplot function (downloaded from MATHWORKS). I solved it by creating an axes object

```
temp_axes = tight_subplot(numSubplotRows, numSubplotColumns);
for a = 1:(numSubplotColumns*numSubplotRows)
    fig_axes{a} = temp_axes(a);
end
```

Then the first time drawing to the plots, I distinguished between the two objects being drawn to the same plot using a nested cell variable. The 1st cell refers to the particular subplot, and the 2nd cell refers to the different objects being drawn to the plot.

```
plts{currentplot}{1} = plot(fig_axes{currentplot}, data_1_x, data_1_y);
plts{currentplot}{2} = plot(fig_axes{currentplot}, data_1_y, data_2_y, 'r.');
```

When updating the plots, I call set, and refer to the plts component

```
set(plts{currentplot}{1}, 'XData', data_1_x, 'YData', data_1_y);
set(plts{currentplot}{2}, 'XData', data_2_x, 'YData', data_2_y);
```

I simplified this code snippet so if it isn't obvious or doesn't work I'm happy to update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).